# Magento 2 Override Unit.phtml and Row.phtml in Magento_Checkout

Tags: magento2, overrides

I am trying to override both `unit.phtml` and `row.phtml` within my `Magento_Checkout` module. I am doing everything that I would normally do but it doesn't seem to be overriding like the other phtml files.

The file is being overwritten on my client and then uploaded to `Magento_Checkout\templates\item\price` but none of the changes i'm making seen to be making a difference.

My goal is to remove the Incl Vat from the cart page and just leave Excl Vat as the standard price.

Comment: filenames are case-sensitive

Comment: I have the same file structure on the server as what I do locally. The same as what the vendor files just without overriding vendor files

Comment: you files start with a capital letter. they must named exactly like the ones in the vendor directory

Comment: I assume you cleaned the caches....

Comment: Sorry yeah, thats just my mis-spelling on here. The files themselves are lower case the same as the vendor files. And yes i've cleared all the cache files. I can override other files just these two dont seem to be working

Comment: can you please upload a picture of the file-structure in your theme? this sounds like you made a typo somewhere

Comment: to be clear. it works on your local machine but not on the server?

Comment: A colleague of mine just found the error. Turns out row.phtml and unit.phtml are located within module-weee rather than the checkout module. At least it was something simple. I appreciate your help non-the-less, cheers :)